# How to generate a module from a webpack plugin and hot replace it

Tags: javascript, webpack-hmr, webpack-plugin

I’m trying to write a webpack plugin for https://github.com/martinandert/babel-plugin-css-in-js, with the following 2 requirements during development:

- I don’t want a file to be written to disk, but instead have webpack-dev-server host the file in-memory.
- I want hot reloading to load the newly extracted CSS.

(Questions are at the bottom.)

---

### Don’t write to disk

I’ve been able to do this with code like the following, but after reading many different examples I’m still not feeling 100% sure that this is the right way.

```
compiler.plugin('emit', function(compilation, callback) {
  compilation.chunks.forEach(function(chunk) {
    chunk.modules.forEach(function(module) {
      if (module.resource) {
        var css = extractCSSFromFile(module.resource)
        if (css) {
          cache[module.resource] = css
        }
      }
    })
  })
  var source = Object.values(cache).join('')
  compilation.assets[bundleFile] = {
    source: function() { return source },
    size: function() { return source.length },
  }
})
```

---

### Hot reload

My thinking is that whenever the CSS changes, I would render a new version of a tiny module which forces the stylesheet to reload. I would then have web pack’s Hot Module Replacement replace that module, thus in effect have HMR for the extracted stylesheet. This reload module looks like:

```
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept()
  module.hot.dispose(function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('link[href="' + WEBPACK_BABEL_CSS_IN_JS_STYLESHEET_PATH + '"]').forEach(link => {
      link.href = link.href.replace(/(\?\d+)?$/, '?' + WEBPACK_BABEL_CSS_IN_JS_STYLESHEET_HASH)
    })
  })
}
```

And the webpack plugin code to generate the file with the hash of the latest CSS looks like:

```
compiler.plugin('emit', function(compilation, callback) {
  // All of the previous code to extract the CSS...

  var source = Object.values(cache).join('')
  var sourceHash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(source).digest('hex')

  var cssReloader = path.basename(bundleFile, '.css') + '_webpack-reloader.js'
  var childCompiler = compilation.createChildCompiler('babel-css-in-js', {
    filename: cssReloader,
  })

  childCompiler.apply(
    new SingleEntryPlugin(
      compiler.context,
      path.join(__dirname, 'webpack-babel-css-in-js-client-template.js'),
      path.join(publicPath, cssReloader))
  )

  childCompiler.apply(
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      WEBPACK_BABEL_CSS_IN_JS_STYLESHEET_PATH: JSON.stringify(path.join(publicPath, bundleFile)),
      WEBPACK_BABEL_CSS_IN_JS_STYLESHEET_HASH: JSON.stringify(sourceHash),
    })
  )

  // Completely cargo-culted from http://stackoverflow.com/a/38284256
  // It is supposedly required for HMR to work.
  childCompiler.plugin('compilation', (compilation) => {
    if (compilation.cache) {
      if (!compilation.cache[cssReloader]) {
        compilation.cache[cssReloader] = {}
      }
      compilation.cache = compilation.cache[cssReloader]
    }
  })

  childCompiler.runAsChild(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      callback(err)
    }
    callback()
  })
})
```

The problem, however, is that my reloader JS module doesn’t get regenerated, which I *think* is because the input source doesn’t change, it would only change during compilation.

---

My questions basically are:

- Am I approaching this the right way? And do you know of the right examples that I should look at?
- Alternatively, is there a way for me to compile a file without using an external input file, but fully from source? That way I can just re-generate the source and embed the hash myself, after which webpack should notice a difference and HMR it, right?